# Disbale "lowercase_normalizer" normalizer while applying aggregation in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

We have applied "lowercase_normalizer" normalizer to fields to achieve case insensitive search. However, we need to perform aggregation on certain fields without any text transformation. Is there any way of disabling the normalizer while aggregating through the records?

Comment: Nope, not possible. That is because during indexing, all the words or tokens are converted into lower case and then it is indexed/saved in Elasticsearch. Since your data itself doesn't have any info, you cannot do anything except reindex it in different keyword field without `lowercase_normalizer` being set and then apply whatever aggregation you'd want on it.

Comment: @OpsterESNinja-Kamal -- so a question/statement, in the document, it will be uppercase, but in the  index lowercase -- when I retrieve it via a query, it will be uppercase, vs when I retrieve it via an aggregation, it will be lowercase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data in the field has already been normalized before indexing, so it is stored in the index in lowercase. I suggest you make a separate field where you don't apply the lowercase_normalizer to be used for aggregations.

Answer (score 1):

You can try my way.

Example your initial mapping is as follows:

```
"test_nor": {
    "type": "keyword",
    "normalizer": "lowerasciinormalizer"
}
```

Data
`"test_nor": "Lê văn Lươn"`

Aggregations look like this

```
{
 "size": 0,
 "aggs": {
     "by_name": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "test_nor",
             "size": 100
         },
         "aggs": {
             "by_email": {
                 "terms": {
                     "field": "email",
                     "size": 100
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }
}
```

Result aggregations

```
"aggregations": {
    "by_name": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
            {
                "key": "le van luon",
                "doc_count": 1,
                "by_email": {
                    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                    "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                    "buckets": [
                        {
                            "key": "email1@gmail.com",
                            "doc_count": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "email2@gmail.com",
                            "doc_count": 1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

You want result aggregations "key": "Lê văn Lươn" right.

1: Update mapping

```
PUT /my-index-000001/_mapping
{
     "properties": {
      "test_nor": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "normalizer": "lowerasciinormalizer",
          "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword"
              }
          }
      }
  }
}
```

2: **Update a data field so that the data gets the new mapping**

3: Update query aggregations

```
{
"size": 0,
"aggs": {
    "by_name": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "test_nor.keyword",
            "size": 100
        },
        "aggs": {
            "by_email": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "email",
                    "size": 100
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

4: So now you got what you want

```
"aggregations": {
    "by_name": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
            {
                "key": "Lê văn Lươn",
                "doc_count": 1,
                "by_email": {
                    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                    "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                    "buckets": [
                        {
                            "key": "email1@gmail.com",
                            "doc_count": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "email2@gmail.com",
                            "doc_count": 1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Hope it helps you !